# How can I use django-tracking package

Tags: python, django, tracking

Im trying django_tracking package ( https://github.com/codekoala/django-tracking ) , I got the instalation.

but i cannot import de models ..
Im trying like this :

```
from tracking.models import Visitor
```

Its return "Unused import: Visitor .Unresolved import: Visitor" for me.. What i doing worng ?
Sorry im beginner in Django.

Comment: Where are you doing this import? Pure Python? Django shell? Some IDE?

Comment: Im doing this import at Eclipse IDE with Pydev plugin ..

Answer (score 0):

I reloaded the python interpreter in Eclipse. It's working now. thanks.